# How to add a remote folder using command line in Resilio Sync?

Tags: linux, sync, bittorrent, resilio-sync

I have a folder that's currently shared by another machine running Resilio Sync (formerly Bittorrent Sync). How do I grant a new machine access to this share using the config file? I don't want to use the web interface as this is a headless server.

Reading the instructions at [Running Sync In Configuration Mode](https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178884-Running-Sync-in-configuration-mode) shows a section of the config file dedicated to shared folders:

```
"shared_folders" :
  [
    {
      "secret" : "MY_SECRET_1", // required field - use --generate-secret in command line to create new secret
      "dir" : "/home/user/resilio/sync_test", // * required field
      "use_relay_server" : true, //  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_tracker" : true,
      "search_lan" : true,
      "use_sync_trash" : true, // enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "overwrite_changes" : false, // restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
      "selective_sync" : false, // add folder in selective sync mode
      "known_hosts" : // specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search
      [
        "192.168.1.2:44444"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And provides the following description:

> 9. Shared folders section: If you set shared folders in config file WebUI will be DISABLED. Shared directories specified in configuration
>      file override the folders previously added from WebUI.
>
> "secret" - use --generate-secret in command line to create new secret
>
> "dir" - edit path to folder
>
> "use_relay_server" - "true" - relay server will be used when connection fails. False = "use_relay_server" is disabled.
>
> "search_lan" - if "true" is selected, Sync will search your local network for **other instances of Sync having the same Keys as yours**. The fastest way to discover other peers in LAN. If you choose to disable this option, either make sure that the use of Tracker server is allowed or configure predefined hosts.
>
> "use_sync_trash" - "true" enables SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices.
>
> "overwrite changes" - "true" restores modified files to original version (only for read-only version). "selective_sync" - adding folder in selective sync mode.
>
> "known hosts" - specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search.

A look at the linux [command line args](https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204762449-Guide-to-Linux-and-Sync-peculiarities) doesn't say much about specifying keys to tie devices together.

Comment: after searching around a bit, I found this tutorial, which shows you how to easily access the Web UI on a headless server - easiest solution imo ;) https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-resilio-sync-btsync-ubuntu-18-04-18-10